# Efficient Data Pipeline for TensorFlow Object Detection API Example

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api

I am using TF Object Detection API example for detecting objects in a video and it seems that data pipeline is bottleneck.

After running the provided example code which does inference on single image, which is very slow and initialize session after each inference, I have accomplished feeding batches using tf-data pipeline. This increased the speed around 10x as compared to single image. Still, during inference, my GPU utilization is around 18% monitored through nvidia-smi.

I would like to have such a data pipeline which can increase the GPU utilization and in return further reduce the inference time.

Here I am sharing two approaches I have used with their respective timings. Example video has 484 frames with resolution of 720x1080 with same batch size of 128 used in both cases.

**Approach 1:**

```py
sess = tf.Session(graph=load_frozen_graph)

def getBatch(start, end):
    loop from start to end:
        #load one image into a numpy array
    return numpy array

loop over num_batches:
    get_inference = sess.run(tensor_dict, feed_dict:{getBatch(start, end)})
```

**Approach 2:**

```py
sess = tf.Session(graph=load_frozen_graph)

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((TEST_IMAGE_PATHS))
dataset = dataset.map(parse_function, num_parallel_calls=8)
dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
dataset = dataset.prefetch(1)
iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
next_element = iterator.get_next()

sess2 = tf.Session()

while True:
    i = i + 1
    try:
        image_batch = sess2.run(next_element)
        get_inference = sess.run(tensor_dict, feed_dict = {image_tensor: image_batch})
    except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
        print("End of training dataset.")
        break
```

**Timing Comparison**

I timed the python script with "time" function like `time python object_detection.py`

```
| Approach 1      | Approach 2       |
| ----------------| ---------------- | 
|real    2m29.634s| real    0m37.005s|
|user    3m46.984s| user    1m44.916s|
|sys     0m32.404s| sys     0m16.404s|
```

Comment: Could we have a look on what you've accomplished?

Comment: You should increase the batch_size, this will improve performance.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro I have already tested by increasing batch_size but it does not increase performance any further as well as GPU utilization.